# Access Scope Within Object Envoked By Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, object, scope, closures, anonymous-function

I know closures exist to keep properties from being accessed outside of their scope, but I'm curious to know if there is a way to inject into one that's nested fairly deep within an object that is envoked by an anonymous function?

```
function() {
 ...
 }({
   421: ...
   420: [function(t, e, n) {
      var o = [].slice;
      e.exports = function(t, e) {
      //insert code here
      "string" == typeof e && (e = t[e]);
      if ("function" != typeof e)
          throw new Error("bind() requires a function");
      var n = o.call(arguments, 2);
      return function() {
          return e.apply(t, n.concat(o.call(arguments)))
        }
      }
    }
  422: ...
})
```

Comment: This looks like it's compiled JS code (maybe from browserify or something?) Where's it coming from? Where are the actual source files located? Could you provide a more specific question - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey Adam, that would make sense. Long story short, I'm trying to fire a Google Tag Manager Datalayer push when a certain function gets called, I have access to inject code snippets into the site via Tag Manager. essentially I'm trying to rewrite a function that looks like this: window.top.analytics.user.traits = function(){e.apply(t, n.concat(o.call(arguments)))}

Comment: go back and start with the source file(s), not the compiled JS.